# Doctrine2 Querying in entities

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

I'm using SF2.1 with Doctrine2

I have 2 entities : Category and Article, linked with a oneToMany relation.

I want to retrieve all articles of a specific category, but only the published ones ....

I show you what I do for the moment :

```
// in /Entity/category.php :
public function getAllArticlesPublished(){
    $articles = array();
    foreach($this->getArticles() as $article){
        if($article->isPublished()) $articles[] = $article;
    }
    return $articles;
}
```

Is this the good way to do it ? It doesn't look good to parse the whole array of Articles ... but I don't want to do this in the repository becauseit concerns a specific Category.

Any hint for me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might take a look at [Filtering Collections](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-associations.html#filtering-collections). If it doesn't solve your problem, then a repository would be the best place for stuff like this.

Comment: I must ask something more ... If my relation has a foreign Table : _Article - ArticleCategory - Category_ Will I still be able to use Criteria to fetch all Articles from Category A that are published ? (published is owned by the Article Entity) , there's no JOIN in Criteria from what I see